# How can I distinguish between Xtext, Xtend and similar Eclipse technologies?

Tags: xtext, xtend

What are the characteristics, differences and similarities of all these Eclipse-based technologies starting with X (Xtext, Xtend)? Are there any more to learn about?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- **[Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)** is a *textual* modelling framework for development of programming languages and domain specific languages.
- **[Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/)** is a JVM language that "*extends*" Java, being fully interoperable with it while having a much nicer syntax. It is to Java like CoffeeScript is to JavaScript.
- **[Xbase](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xbase)** is a partial programming language implemented in Xtext and is meant to be embedded and extended within other programming languages and domain-specific languages (DSL) written in Xtext. Xtend is also *based* upon it.
- **[Xcore](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore)** is a convenient textual syntax for *Ecore* metamodels.
- (**[Xpand](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xpand)** is a language specialized on code generation based on EMF models, now *deprecated* in favor of Xtend.)
- (**[Xpect](http://www.xpect-tests.org/)** is a unit- and integration-testing framework that stores test data in any kind of text files and is based on JUnit. It is implemented in Xtext and is a 3rd party project.)